# How to add libraries in Visual Studio in a Linux cross-compilation project?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, cross-compiling, libraries, raspberry-pi3

I'm new to Linux (rpi 3) and trying to create a window application on it from my Windows PC with Visual Studio. Creating a console-application is no problem, since it doesn't require any libraries.

And the way I understood it is that there is no real standard Linux library for GUIs like Win32 on Windows, so you need to add external libraries.
I went for QT and downloaded already compiled files from qtrpi.com for the rpi3.

I added the lib path for the linker and the include path for the compiler on the projects properties page, but all I get is

```
1>/home/pi/projects/WindowProject/main.cpp:2:27: fatal error: QtGui\qwindow.h: No such file or directory
1>#include <QtGui\qwindow.h>
1>                          ^
```

What am I missing? This works without a problem on normal projects, only that it wouldn't run, since it is for Linux.